# Far Manager and QuickEdit mode, Far seems to be disable it

Tags: far-manager

**Context**

I try to turn on QuickEdit mode for my Far Manager window, but after I check the box and close the Properties window, then show the Properties windows again, it is turned off.

**Question**

Is there any way to get the QuickEdit seamlessly work (btw I only would like the right click  paste)?

[image]

Comment: How are you closing it?  Are you hitting the X on the top, or clicking on the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Far [Changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FarGroup/FarManager/master/far/changelog) you can find the following entries:

> t-rex 18.12.2009 17:59:11 +0200 - build 1285
>
> 1. At users' requests, an addition to 1282, if Mouse option is off in Far interface settings, then additional console mode “quick edit” isn't switched off if the shortcut/window setting is on.

> t-rex 13.12.2009 00:40:22 +0200 - build 1282
>
> 2. Additional console modes (quick edit/insert mode) are switched off while Far is running, but if they have been turned on when Far is started then they are back on for the time external programs run in Far window.

From my testing, you could disable the Mouse (`Options » Interface settings » Mouse`) in Far Manager, and then Quick Edit works (but you can't use the mouse in far anymore).

If you need to paste in other applications, started from Far Manager, enable the `QuickEdit Mode` in the *default* settings for Far Manager (shortcut) and restart Far.